# NServiceBus design ideas

Tags: nservicebus

Can any developers/architects with experience with NServiceBus offer guidance and help on the following?

We have a requirement in the business (and not a lot of money) to create a robust interface between an externally hosted application and our internal ERP's (yup, more than one).

When certain activities take place in the third party application they will send us the message. i.e. call a web service passing various fields of information in the message etc. We are not in control nor can we change this third party application.

My responsibility is creating this web service and the processing of the messages into each ERP. The third party dictates how the web service will look, but not what its responsible for. We have to accept that if they get a response back of 'success' then we at this point have taken responsibility for that message! i.e. we need to ensure as close to perfect no data loss takes place.

This is where I'm interested in the use of NServiceBus. Use it to store/accept a message at first. At this point I get lost, I can't tell what should happen, i.e. what design follows. Does another machine (process) subscribe and grab the message to process it into an ERP, if so since each ERPs integration logic differs do I make a subscriber per ERP? A message may have two destination ERP targets however, so is it best the message is sent and not subscribed to.

Obviously in the whole design, I need to have some business rules which help determine the destination ERP's and then business rules that determine what actually takes place with in each ERP. So I also have a question on BRE's but this can wait although still may be a driver for what the message has to do.

so:

Third party > web service call > store message (& return success) > determine which ERP is target > process each into ERP > mark message complete

If anything fails along the lines making sure the message does not get lost. p.s. how does MSMQ prevent loss since the whole machine may die ? is this just disk resilience etc?

Many thanks if you've read and even more for any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect application for NServiceBus.

Your web service should ONLY parse the request from the third and translate it into an NServiceBus message, which it should `Bus.Send()`.  You don't respond with a 200 status code until that message is on the Bus, at which point, you are responsible for it, and NServiceBus's built-in error/retry and error queue facilities become your best friend.

This message should be received by another endpoint, but it needs to be able to account for duplicate messages or use idempotence so that duplicates aren't a problem.  If the third party hits your web service, and the message is successfully placed on the bus, but then some error prevents them from receiving the 200 response code, you will get duplicates from them.

At this point, the endpoint receiving the MessageFromWebServiceCommand message could `Bus.Publish()` a SomeBusinessEventHappenedEvent that contains the command data.

For each ERP, create an additional endpoint that subscribes to the SomeBusinessEventHappenedEvent and uses your business logic to decide what to do respective to that ERP.  In some cases, that "something" may be "nothing".  Keep idempotence in mind here too, because if the message fails it will be retried.

All the other things you're worried about (preventing loss of messages, what happened if machines die) will be taken care of thanks to NServiceBus and MSMQ being naturally resilient to such problems.

Here is a blog post, including a sample project, that shows how to receive messages from an external partner via a web service and handle them with NServiceBus, and a link straight to the sample project on GitHub:

- [Robust 3rd Party Integrations with NServiceBus](http://www.make-awesome.com/2011/11/robust-3rd-party-integrations-with-nservicebus/)

  - [Project Source Code on GitHub](https://github.com/DuctTapeMan/NServiceBus-External-WebService-Example)

Comment: I'd recommend using a saga for this kind of integration rather than a Bus.Publish. The saga could then also deal with the issues of idempotence (by giving it a long enough timeout).

Comment: @David - Would the same one message be processed by all ERP's or does the message get duplicated? i.e. how does error handling occur on this. As a group of ERPs or per one ERP. Either way what happens to the main message? Sorry for the novice questions.

Comment: @ Udi - can you expand on saga compared to that of Davids response? How does it work in described scenario?

@anyone - How is nservicebus licensed? Per server using a message? If so may prove too expensive for us.

Comment: When the message is published, each subscriber gets its own copy of the message. Each subscriber does its own error handling.  So if you had 3 subscribers and 2 failed handling the message, you'd have 2messages in error queue(s) from each of the endpoints that failed, and the 3rd endpoint would have succeeded in its task.

Comment: On sagas, it's kind of like a memory between processing messages, with data stored in saga state.  When the first message comes in it will start a saga and request a timeout from the Timeout Manager - let's say 5 minutes.  If another message comes in (because of the duplicated messages problem) the saga will say "Ah, I see I already know about that. Let's wait a bit longer." or maybe "Oh, I see the data in the message has changed, let's make note of that."  (continued...)

Comment: At the end of your timeout, the Timeout Manager sends a message back to your Saga. The Saga state is looked up, and at this point perhaps you can be confident that no additional messages will be coming in, and THEN publish the event for the ERPs.  Or, if there is some dependency between the ERP endpoints, your saga can do some sort of orchestration where first it sends a message to ERP Endpoint 1, and when that returns it can send a message to ERP Endpoint 2, etc. But then of course the Saga needs to know about the ERP endpoints, vs publishing where the publisher would be unaware.

Comment: I'm not too sure how the SAGA helps in my circumstance then. Waiting a fixed amount of time for a bunch of messages is of no interest. 1 message will come in from the web service, and 5 erp's need to process that message. The erp's don't have to care for each others success or fail. Each erp should however care for its own success or fail and retry at that point. Is non saga the way to go? ..and can each subscriber be on the same server with its own message queue?

Comment: ....In the above, does nservicebus need to be licensed on the server running the web service (creating the first message) and on the subscribed destinations server(s)?

Comment: It all depends on how rigid your business requirements are and how you deal with failures.  What happens if you receive the message in your web service, the message gets successfully put on the Bus, but a network failure causes your 200 OK response to never be received, and so your external client tries to send the message again?  If it's OK for all the ERPs to process that message more than once, then you don't really need a Saga.  If that would be a bad thing, then a Saga can help you to achieve that once-and-only-once behavior.

Comment: In your scenario, we have agreed with the external party that if they recieve an 'OK' response we have taken responsibility. However if they don't, they will try sending the message again later. The message being recieved comes with a transaction id. This id is unique and so we have to confirm it doesn't already exisit in the queue to prevent duplicate messages. In that scenario an error response with an agreed error code would be sent back, stating duplicate hence its ok to assume its been previously received. Can this validation be done, i.e. can the queue be queried?...

Comment: We do want to confirm we have the message and its only handled once by each ERP. Each ERP can be uniquely handled. i.e. if ERP1 fails, ERP1 needs to know this and try process that message again but it has no impact on whether ERP2 & 3 succeeds or not.

Comment: You can't check the queue for duplicates. Instead of a "duplicate request" error, just reply back "Yep, we got it". There's really no difference from the client perspective. Then the Saga would look at that duplicate transaction ID and either publish to the ERPs or not based on whether it had seen that transaction ID before. The fact that you have this unique transaction ID makes things a lot easier - you shouldn't have to worry about timeouts unless you want to clean up your saga data at some point.

Comment: I do feel silly but I still can't understand the saga in respect of how it / the design fits into my needs. Not easy given the shortness of these comments but can you explain what part of the whole process would be a saga and how that differs from an alternative approach. How does using a saga enable the 'check for if duplicate' logic? I'd never need to process a duplicate. Also don't understand the timeout/cleanup comment either but that's prob because I don't get the saga thing.

Comment: I've been putting research into the saga pattern (if it is indeed a pattern). Any how I've come to understand much more about it and what it is and why/when it should be used. Issue being now, I really don't know why saga would be recommended for my scenario. It seems only if processing was based on waiting for more than one message would a saga be useful. In my scenario one message needs to be processed albeit to maybe numerous destinations. Unless I had the requirement to deal with the many destinations as a transaction I can't see where a saga helps, a message isn't reliant on another!?

Comment: I decided it would be easier to create some sample code than to try to keep explaining in 600-character chunks. I edited my answer with links to the source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read, I agree these comments don't seem to work well in a thread like fashion.